# How to open .diary files

Tags: android

last year I've been using this Private Diary app and I've been entering data for almost 5 months. After that, i changed the phone and couldn't open the data, somehow i restored some of them, but still couldn't open them on my Samsung. I saved them on my computer as files .diary. Is there any program for converting or opening files that are DIARY File (.DIARY) ?

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.diaryfree

Comment: Because it's a private app. Means private ending. I don't believe you'll find what you're looking for. I would suggest you to try contacting the app developers for help. I'm sure they have the tools for you.

Comment: I sent them more than 3 mails, but they're not responding. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: No Problem! Hope you'll figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing the file extension `.diary` to `.txt` and open the file. There is a small chance that this might work, if the file is not encrypted. Else, you will have to contact the app developers for help.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you solve the problem?
If you use the same diary app on new phone just use restore from backup to restore your files from .diary file, or use Synchro button to synchro with your web  version of the diary.
All the files .diary are jpeg files. You can open them with any image viewer.

As to developer - he sucks. I have paid version and never got reply from him.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as you. The .diary file is actually an image file that can be opened once you changed the file extension to .jpg file.

If you are looking for text records, you could find them in the PrivateDiaryBackup.zip in you Samsung, outside the PrivateDiary folder. There is a .db file there that could be opened using sqlitebrowser.